# loading view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

HI I have a codeigniter controller called CIcontroller and I have a method say redirectmethod

in the redirectmethod i have some code and then i do this

```
$data['redirect_page'] = 'page_name';
$this->load->view('template_view',$data);
```

the template view basically loads header footer and the corresponding view as specified by the data parameter

Now everything works fine but my url has value `http:\\blabla\CIcontroller\redirectmethod` instead of `http:\\blabla\page_name`

could anyone help me fix this thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to emit a Location header to tell the browser to load a different page. See `redirect` in the [url helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Comment: could I pass data with redirect like redirect('template_view', $data)

Comment: No, but you could serialize the object and keep it in a session.